# Magento - Multi Store view - product name for each store

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm using Magento 1.9.0.1

I have a store in English, I want to have the same store (same categories and products) just translated to Spanish.

I used this tutorial to achive this: http://sherodesigns.com/magento-tutorial-creating-multi-language-stores/

I created another store view in my store. Under System->Configuration->General->General->Locale Options->Locale for the Spanish store view, I un-checked the "Use Website" and selected "Spanish".

Under Catalog->Manage Categories I changed the store view to Spanish and I translated the Name of each category to Spanish.

Under Catalog->Manage Products I changed the store view to Spanish and I translated the Name of each product to Spanish.

Now, In the frontend, when I switched the the Spanish store view (using the language switcher), I can see my store in Spanish, including the categories and products.

But when I add a product (that I can see in Spanish in the category page) to the shopping cart and goes to the shopping cart, I can see the product, but is name is in English (although I'm in the Spanish store view). Also under Order Review in the Checkout page it's in English.

What can be the problem? How can I fix it?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I upgraded my store to 1.9.2.3 and it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Create Store view for Spanish. change Locale Option in System->configuration->General->Locale Option

Please check below link for reference

http://www.magentech.com/documentation/how-to-setup-a-magento-multi-language-website/

https://www.ubertheme.com/docs/setup-multiple-languages-currencies/